# failed to launch stub for playground execution

Tags: xcode

I am trying to work in the playground. But can not execute even the simplest code like

```
print("hello world")
```

I am getting an error saying:

failed to launch stub for playground execution: error: could not find a process named Untitled Page

(Untitled Page is the name of my playground page)

yesterday everything was working fine. I already cleaned the module cache of Xcode, removed derived date.... Restarted my mac, opened and closed Xcode .... error still remains as it is.
Please help! I am using Xcode 7.3 and OSX 10.11.3

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was gone after I updated to 7.3.1 Xcode.

Comment: I just had the same problem on Xcode8, but I just quit Xcode and opened again and the problem just went away

Answer (score 2):

If you have opened Xcode using rosetta, then it will be the issue.

For that: Open Finder -> Go to Aplications ->Right Click Xcode -> Select Get info -> Uncheck rosetta

Boom!

Comment: this worked for me. Xcode 14.2, OS Ventura 13.2.1, M1 Pro