# Compiler segmentation fault while using Set in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4, xcode9

This code works fine:

```
let lines = ["one", "one", "two"]
let lineSet = lines
```

but while compiling this one:

```
let lines = ["one", "one", "two"]
let lineSet = Set(lines)
```

I'm getting:

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

I've got Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235). Is this is really a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

My workaround for now:

```
var lineSet = Set<String>()
let lines = ["one", "one", "two"]
lines.forEach { lineSet.insert($0) }
```

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] of this?

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code that you have? Have you tried this in a new playground or project? Is this definitely the line you're crashing on or could it be another line?

Comment: Yeah, It's not a first time when I've got the same problem with `Set` on Swift 3 everything was okay.

Comment: Your error example compiles just fine for me.

Comment: There's something else going on here. Try doing your code in a brand-new playground and seeing if it works.

Comment: Same result as in the question. So I think I'll just reinstall xcode, because programming without using `Set` is just painful...

Comment: don't forget to clear your derived data

Comment: A compiler segfault is _always_ a bug.

Comment: @JoshCaswell you mean an Xcode/playground bug, or something related to *his* code?

Comment: @JakubPomykała FYI my answer finally got undeleted my a moderator...

Comment: Cleaning derived data and reinstalling xcode helped me. Now I can use `Set` yay.. :)

Comment: In the compiler, @Honey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better, more idiomatic way to construct your `lineSet` is simply:

```
let lineSet: Set = ["one", "one", "two"]
```

Hope this fixes your compiler crash. Unfortunately, I was unable to fully reproduce your original issue, so I can't really confirm my fix will be any different ;)

As already mentioned, deleting your `DerivedData` folder is a good idea (also `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` might help as well). A somewhat standard practice when Xcode starts behaving erratically.

Answer (score -6):

Quoting John Caswell from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531754/compiler-segmentation-fault-while-using-set-in-swift/46534122#comment80059741_46531754)

> A compiler segfault is **always** a bug

In my experience, Playgrounds is a bit buggy. XCode Playground gets stuck on "running playground" or "launching simulator", and then won't run the code. I get errors like this from time to time, and others have run into non-reproducible issues:

- [XCode hangs every time when i write few lines of code in playground](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31007759)
- https://teamtreehouse.com/community/xcode-playground-gets-stuck-on-running-and-wont-run-the-code-what-to-do
- https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/playground-hangs-frequently/7331
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75045
- [failed to launch stub for playground execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877419/failed-to-launch-stub-for-playground-execution)
- [Playground execution failed: error: Couldn't lookup symbols - Playground in xcode using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491216/playground-execution-failed-error-couldnt-lookup-symbols-playground-in-xcod)
- https://ericasadun.com/2015/03/16/swift-working-around-sources-playground-bugs/

(Although some of these links are old, Playground isn't that mature yet.)

Usually, the fix is to close Xcode, change your cursor's position, etc.

As a result, I either use https://repl.it/site/languages/swift, use Playground with caution, or use the latest Xcode (because that usually has the least amount of bugs).

**EDIT:**

Still when I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 both on my macbook air and macbook pro, Xcode crashes or just stops working on playground. Same thing for my colleague. Sometimes even when I'm just in Chrome the Playground just crashes!

I've been told that if you open Utilities and then toggle your platform from iOS to macOS then you may be able to resolve your Playground's freezing/hanging. But I haven't tried that.

Comment: I don't think his original issue was Playground-related but, anyway, I kind of agree with your remarks about Playground overall stability ;)